# cyclomatic complexity on spring controller method: **Best Practice**

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a `spring-boot` controller that gets data from `service` and return `thymeleaf html` page. Everything works fine.

The problem here is i have to create bunch of list and map that will be used by `thymeleaf` and controller method is getting bigger.

```
   @Controller
    public class MyController {

        @Autowired
        MyService myService; 

        @RequestMapping("/my-page")
        public String getMypage(Model model) {

            //get data from service

            //i have alot of code to extract data and prepare different list to be used by thymeleaf

        }
}
```

Now my question is about **best practice**.

Is it good idea to create method inside controller so code would be more readable something like below

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService; 

    @RequestMapping("/my-page")
    public String getMypage(Model model) {

        //get data from service

        myMethod1();
        //some code here
        //myMethod2();
        // code here

    }

    private void myMethod1(){

        //myMethod 1 code here
    }

    private void myMethod2(){

        //method 2 code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's for sure a good idea.

Do you know the book Clean Code from Robert C. Martin:

https://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Comment: Yes I read that book. I am confused about  if doing so is good  practice on controller class or not.

Comment: Yes it is. Why are you confused